# Foobar2000: How to get preferences for Main Window and Notification Area?

Tags: windows, foobar2000

I have multiple portable installations of Foobar2000 beside the main installation.

I have tested different installations (testing different skins with different features) and lost track of the origin of the fact that the main installation as well as others have certain settings for Main Window and Notification Area that I haven't noticed before.

[image]

...while others (like any fresh installations) don't have them.

[image]

Each of the foobar2000 installations that have these settings have also different column-based skins. (But the settings are not registered under Columns UI, nor under the Default UI, but under the general Display section).

What are the components needed for this?

---

Update after answer:

Components list of portable installation that has these settings:

[image]
[image]

The skin used is [this](http://www.deviantart.com/art/Foobar2000-Momo-399099411).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [foo_UI_hacks](http://foobar2000.ru/forum/download/file.php?id=2022&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;filename=foo_ui_hacks_2013-02-19.zip) component will give you those options.

This was visible from the posted image, because the Preference window displays the name of the selected component in its title:

[image]

Comment: If my answer above is incorrect, please add a screenshot of your components list.

Comment: It is not FooOnScreenDisplay, which appears in the settings like seen [here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/images/1/12/Osd_config.PNG). See update for components.

Comment: Updated. UI hacks gives you those options.

Comment: tested and confirmed

Comment: i see the link for the component is not working now (asks for login), so i edited that